# display:inline-box and filling remaining height

Tags: html, css

```css
.container{
width:100%;
height:100%;
background:red;
}

body, html{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.box{
  display:inline-block;
  width:15%;
  height:50%;
  background:black;
  vertical-align:top;
  border:1px solid blue;
}
*{
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  font-size:0;

}
.one{
  height:30%;
}
.two{
height:70%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    
    
  </div>
  <div class="box one"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box two"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  
</div>
```

Is it possible to have the div on the bottom start where the tiny div on top starts?
I was going to achieve this by making columns and then separating them into 2 div's but I was wondering if there's an alternative way besides flexbox and other JS libraries.  Also, no gimmick like margin-top:-50px on bottom div.  Looking for a fluid solution.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you're going for?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jzhang172/o1ho0c3e/
In the first column is the result I want but was wondering if it's possible to do this without creating a column for each.